# Is the TP4056 for lithium polymer or lithium ion batteries?

Tags: battery-charging, lipo

Can I use jit for charging Li-Po?

[image]

Comment: Yes.,.,..............

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct name of the 'LiPo' battery, is 'lithium-ion polymer' battery. dropping the 'ion' part makes some confusions but it's still a Li-ion battery. so yes. you can use that chip for charging LiPo batteries.

> **A lithium polymer battery, or more correctly lithium-ion polymer
> battery** (abbreviated as LiPo, LIP, Li-poly, lithium-poly and others),
> is a rechargeable battery of lithium-ion technology using a polymer
> electrolyte instead of a liquid electrolyte.

from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_polymer_battery).